# Can find one file in a directory but not another in the same directory?

Tags: java

I have a server running in src/server/ServerApp.java. When a client connects and asks for something like response.html it searches "src/webapps/" for the file like this:

```
    File f = new File("src/webapps/" + request);
    if (!f.exists())
    {
        statusCode = "404 Not Found";
    }
```

Where request is the resource asked for (in this case request="response.html"). This works for the file named `response.html` but there is a file in the same directory called `test.unk` where `.unk` is a file name that I made up and the file only contains text.

When I get to the if statement, it recognized `response.html` but `test.unk` apparently does not exist.

Am I trying to access these files correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's related to eclipse

Comment: It is not related to eclipse.

Comment: Could you give a little more code? It might be another issue. E.g. are there no whitespaces, are you sure it is exactly here that the file apparently doesn't exit, etc?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that right here is the problem. If I specify the complete path like:
File f = new File("D:\\MyDocs\\workspace\\project\\src\\webapps\\" + request);
It works fine, but I shouldn't have to do that, right?

Comment: Maybe a server using another directory for compiled application, like `target`?

Comment: I'm unsure I understand what you mean.

Comment: If you add `System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());` to your code what it displays?

Comment: I suspect that there's a problem with case or with unprintable characters.

Comment: @mmdw, with that line of code you made me realize my error! Thank you!